# Ordering the positive integers $n$ in nonascending order of $\pi(n)/n$

Tags: number-theory, prime-numbers

For any two positive integers $n$ and $m$, write $n \succ m$ if $\pi(n)/n > \pi(m)/m$, where $\pi(x)$ is the prime counting function, and write $n \sim m$ if $\pi(n)/n = \pi(m)/m$.  Thus, $n \succ m$ if and only if the probability that a randomly selected number from $1$ to $n$ is prime is greater than the probability that a randomly selected number from $1$ to $m$ is prime.  This orders the positive integers as follows:
$$3 \succ 5 \succ 7 \succ 2 \sim 4 \sim 6 \sim 8 \succ 13 \succ 11 \succ 9 \succ 14 \succ 19 \succ 12 \succ 17 \succ 10 \sim 15 \sim 20 \succ 23 \succ 18 \succ \cdots \succ 1.$$
A number $n$'s position in the sequence tells you, relative to numbers in other positions, how lucky you would be for randomly choosing a number less than or equal to $n$ and having it be prime.  Of course, the number $3$ maximizes this probability, with $\pi(3)/3 = 2/3$.

This sequence is really interesting to me.

Note that $n$ is prime if and only if $n \succ n-1$, and $n>7$ is the larger of two twin primes if and only if $n \succ n-2 \succ n-1$.  Thus, the primes and the twin primes are encoded in this preordering.

Under this preordering, the primes $p_n$ are ordered according to the OEIS sequence: https://oeis.org/A350778.  Thus, in other words,
$$p_2 \succ p_3 \succ p_4 \succ p_1 \succ p_6 \succ p_5 \succ \cdots,$$
that is,
$$3 \succ 5 \succ 7 \succ 2 \succ 13 \succ 11 \succ \cdots.$$

Also interesting is that there are clumps of numbers with $\pi(n)/n$ equal to $1/2$, or $3/8$, or $2/5$, or $1/3$, or $1/4$, and a relatively large clump of numbers with $\pi(n)/n = 1/5$, namely $330\sim 335 \sim 340 \sim 350 \sim 355\sim 360$.

Note that, since by the prime number theorem $\pi(n)/n$ is asymptotic to $1/\log n$, the sequence gets much harder to compute the further out you go, as the values of $\pi(n)/n$ will be more clumped together.   Even just between $41$ and $43$, one has
$$43 \succ 37 \succ 34 \succ 28 \succ 47 \succ 44 \succ 41.$$

I'm curious about properties of this sequence but can't find much about it online.  Does anyone know anything more about the sequence, or know any references that study it?

Comment: For all $x \geq 355991$, $\frac{1}{\log(x)} (1 + \frac{1}{\log(x)}) < \frac{\pi(x)}x < \frac{1}{\log(x)} (1 + \frac{1}{\log(x)} + \frac{2.51}{\log^2(x)})$, so if $\frac{1}{\log(m)} (1 + \frac{m}{\log(m)} + \frac{2.51}{\log^2(m)}) \leq \frac{1}{\log(n)} (1 + \frac{1}{\log(n)})$, $n \succ m$.

Comment: This means you only need to sort $n + o(n)$ values to get the first $n$ actual values in the sequence

Comment: Nice!  Just a small typo, your $\frac{m}{\log m}$ should be $\frac{1}{\log m}$.